# Android Create Google Contact Through Google People Api

Tags: android, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I am new at Google People API. I am able to fetch contacts through api, but I couldnt figure out how to create contacts. As api documantation says I need to use this code block;

```
Person contactToCreate = new Person();
List names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add(new Name().setGivenName("John").setFamilyName("Doe"));
contactToCreate.setNames(names);
Person createdContact = peopleService.people().createContact(contactToCreate).execute();
```

But createContact is giving *"Cannot resolve method 'createContact(com.google.api.services.people.v1.model.Person)' "* error. How can I solve this problem ? Or are there another ways to create Google Contact ?

Comment: It looks like the java client library link hasn't been updated.  I'll take a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug with the automatic java client library code generation. The bug has been resolved and the latest version 125 has the contact endpoints. Follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/people/v1/libraries to install the latest library.